# トップのバッジリストの余白の表示がつぶれている

Tags: バグ, 完了, デザイン, バッジ

下記の通り、トップページの「最近のバッジ」の余白の表示がおかしいです。

具体的には、バッジの上下のスペースが詰まっているような感じになっており、以前はバッジの上下に余白があったように記憶しています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 投稿時の心がけとして、画像をいきなり貼るより言葉での説明を先に書いた方が読み手に取ってより親切かなと思います。 / 「デザインが崩れている」とは具体的にどの部分を指していますか？(本来ならどのように表示されるべきと考えていますか？) 英語版やMSEでは特に話題に上がっていなさそうですし、以前からこの表示のされ方だった気がします。参考: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tstOS.png , https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/352943

Comment: 追記しました。 バッジが上下にくっついているのを指して、バグっているのではないか、という指摘をしています。参考に挙げてくださった画像でも、バッジは上下に空白があるように見受けられます。

Comment: 「表示が崩れる」だと「上下左右の位置がズレる」などのイメージが強いので、今回のケースであれば "余白" の部分を強調した方が意図が伝わりやすいと思います。 / ネットワーク全体で再現しているようなので、MSE にも投稿しておきました。- https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360533

Comment: ありがとうございます。また、指摘をうけて、質問のタイトルを編集しました。

Comment: I'm marking this as [tag:status-deferred] and it'll be addressed as part of our bug duty rotation ^_^（こちらのタグを延期と付け替えまして、今後はバグデューティローテーションの一環として対処される予定です ^_^ ）

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2021-04-20 時点で、[MSE に投稿した要望](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360533) が "status-completed" (対応済み) となっており、実際の表示も修正されたようです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]